# How 2 micro services maintain session and exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, exception, microservices

How exception thrown from one micro service handled by another micro service?
Do we need to copy same exception object on both instances?

Also how session is maintained within micro services?

Comment: Micro services is a design paradigm. So please mention what constitutes your microservice? Is it an API, docker container,  etc?

Comment: However your microservice should not depend on other services, hence it will fail the sole purpose of microservices - independent small services that are meant for 1 job. You should get the result of other micro service execution and check if it passed or not, without maintaing any sessions or cookie like objects.

Comment: How do you communicate between the microservices? And microservices are stateless so there is no session

Answer (score 0):

When one service(Service A) requests another service(Service B), the Requested Service usually gives requested data if everything goes fine. Otherwise, it gives an error code. For more information on the error code, you can see the following document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status.

You can Use JWT token for tracking requester.